# Set union of elements in different files

Tags: shell, file-io, bigdata

I have multiple files like that:

```
file1:

item1
item2
item3

file2:

item1
item5
item3

file3:

item2
item1
item4
```

I want to have a file with all the unique elements. I could do that with Python, only problem being that each file contains various million lines and I wanted to know if there is better method (maybe using only shell scripts?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the elements in common between all three files, another approach is to use a few `grep` operations:

```
$ grep -F -f file1 file2 > file1inFile2
$ grep -F -f file1 file3 > file1inFile3
$ grep -F -f file1inFile2 file1inFile3 > elementsInCommon
```

The `-f` option specifies searching against a file of patterns (`file1` and `file1inFile2` in this case). The `-F` option does a fixed string search.

If you use `bash`, you can do a fancy one-liner:

```
$ grep -F -f <(grep -F -f file1 file2) <(grep -F -f file1 file3) > elementsInCommon
```

Grep searches in sublinear time, I think. So this may get around the usual *O(n log n)* time cost of presorting very large files with the `sort|uniq` approach.

You might be able to speed up a fixed-string `grep` operation even further, [specifying](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/ssh/speed-up-grep-searches-with-lc-all) the `LC_ALL=C` environment variable. However, when I explored this, it seems to be a shell default. Still, given the time improvement that is reported, this setting seems worth investigating if you use `grep`.

Grep may use a fair amount of memory loading patterns, though, which could be an issue given the size of your input files. You might use your smallest of the three files as the pattern source.

If your inputs are already sorted, however, you can walk through each file one line at a time, testing string equality between the three lines. You then either move some input file pointers ahead by a line, or print the equal string that is common to the three inputs. This approach uses *O(n)* time (you walk though each file once) and *O(1)* memory (you buffer three lines). More time, but much less memory. Not sure if this can be done with `bash` built-ins or core utilities, but this is definitely doable with Python, Perl, C, etc.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
cat * | uniq
```

or there may be efficiency gains if each file contains repeats in itself:

```
for file in *; do cat $file | uniq; done | uniq
```

If they aren't sorted files, uniq doesn't work, so this may not be more efficient, as you will need:

```
for file in *; do sort $file | uniq; done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Some comments:  1.) most modern `sort` knows the `-u`, so you can use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq` 2.) The 3rd example woul not save much against the simpler `sort -u files`. Anyway +1. ;) (and [Don't abuse the cat](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html))